# How can I Export an imported dynamic web project as a WAR file using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, export, war

maybe could sound like an obvious question but I'm stuck with this problem since long time ago.

I have bunch of working dynamic web projects to import in Eclipse and I usually import them like File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace -> Select Archive File because the project is .zip.

The problem is when i try to export it as WAR file in order to try it as localhost on TomCat, the imported project doesn't show up as one of the possible project to be exported. The only solution that I found is to create a new dynamic web project and to copy every single file and then when I try to export it as war it works, but is very uncomfortable and requires much time.

Am I missing something, is there anything that I have to change to the project imported to make it work? or is just the way it is?

Comment: How were those projects originally exported?

Comment: @nitind the project is .zip already deployed

Comment: Again, *how*? It's not the same information as the resulting file. As for the zip file, did it include the `.settings` folder and contents, as well as the `.project` file in the root of the project? And why the mention of WAR file?